# Networkx write_graphml gets killed for using to much memory

Tags: networkx

I am building a graph using Networkx which when being written to disk using write_graphml starts to fill up all the RAM and swap memory in the machine, eventually getting killed by the python JVM.
Why would this happen and how can it be fixed/overcome? 
Thanks